# Definition of subgroup of abelian group $G$ generated by subset $A$

Tags: group-theory

In my book I have the following definition for subgroups of a group $G$ generated by $A$, a subset of G:

$$\langle A\rangle=\{x_1^{\epsilon_1}x_2^{\epsilon_2}...x_n^{\epsilon_n}\mid x_i\in A,~\epsilon_i\in\mathbb Z,~ x_i \neq x_{i+1} ,~ n=1,2,3...\}$$

I have no trouble understanding this. But then we define the subgroup of an abelian group $G$ generated by a subset $A$:

$$\langle A\rangle=\{x_1^{\epsilon_1}x_2^{\epsilon_2}...x_k^{\epsilon_k}\mid x_i\in A,~\epsilon_i\in\mathbb Z \text{ for each } i\}$$

I fail to understand how this implies that we can commute the $x_i$'s. Could somebody please explain to me how the commutative property follows from this?

Answer (score 2):

The commutative property doesn't follow from that definition per se.  However since $G$ is abelian and the elements of $A$ multiply according to the multiplication rules for $G$, we get commutativity for free.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to remember that you are assuming that $G$ is abelian from the start. Therefore the elements of $A$ commute with each other.